# Как использовать gettext в Python для многих языков?

Tags: python, gettext

уважаемое сообщество! У меня есть задача использования библиотеки gettext в Python для поддержки нескольких языков в моем проекте. Я уже создал файлы .po и .mo для каждого поддерживаемого языка, и они находятся в директории "translations".

Моя цель - переключаться между языками в зависимости от выбора пользователя и отображать соответствующие тексты в моем приложении.

Однако у меня возникли трудности, и приложение всегда выводит текст на английском языке, несмотря на выбранный язык. Что я делаю не так? Как можно правильно использовать gettext для многих языков в Python?

Спасибо за вашу помощь!
Вот кусок кода, который я попробовал:

```
import gettext


supported_languages = ['ar', 'ru']

for lang in supported_languages:
    translation = gettext.translation('messages', localedir='translations', languages=[lang])
    _ = translation.gettext
    translation.install()


SYSTEM_PROMPT_MESSAGE = _("Hello World")
print(SYSTEM_PROMPT_MESSAGE)
```

Comment: 1 - с одним языком работает? 2 - папку translations вообще находит?